# There is an empty file after updating

Tags: php, curl, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to update an existing document with help of Google Docs API. I'm using PHP+Curl. The `gdata.class.php` is base class. Updating finishes partly. A old content is cleaned. But a new content is not created. According to documentation, I send PUT-request (initial request) to address

```
http://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/document%123456
```

There are Etag of the document and the empty request body. I recive  the status code `200 Ok` and the unique upload URI like this:

```
http://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/document%123456?upload_id=EnB2Uob7DWcFVJTX3oF8sdVv9koZTHacngmM_
```

What should I do???

1. I'm sending the file content and headers to the unique upload URI:

   > ```
   > [0] => Content-Length: 6 
   > [1] => Content-Range: bytes 0-5/6 
   > [2] => Content-Type: text / plain
   > ```

   The responce is recived:

   > HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete

   Headers not contains the "Range" header. It's strange.
   **Result**: the target file is not changed.
2. I'm sending the file content and headers to the unique upload URI:

   > ```
   > [0] => Content-Length: 6
   > [1] => Content-Type: text/plain
   > ```

   The responce is recived:

   > ```
   > HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   > ```

   There is atom+xml in the body.
   **Result**: the target file became an empty.

P.s. The `curl_getinfo` function returns `"5"`. It's not depends on size of the file.

Comment: What parameter in curl_getinfo returned 5?

Comment: This is the CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it asks you to use PUT method, then tell CURL to use it..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
```